# How do I cancel a text selection after the initial mousedown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a pop-up menu based on a click-and-hold, positioned so that a (really) slow click will still trigger the default action, and with the delay set so that a text-selection gesture won't usually trigger the menu.

What I can't seem to do is cancel the text-selection in a way that doesn't prevent text-selection in the first place: returning false from the event handler (or calling `$(this).preventDefault()`) prevents the user from selecting at all, and the obvious `$().trigger('mouseup')` doesn't doesn't do anything with the selection at all.

- This is in the general context of a page, not particular to a textarea or other text field.
- `e.stopPropogation()` doesn't cancel text-selection.
- I'm not looking to *prevent* text selections, but rather to *veto* them after some short period of time, if certain conditions are met.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('myInputField');
if (input) {
    input.onmousedown = function(e) {

        if (!e) e = window.event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

    }
}
```

And if not, have a read of:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Comment: The problem is that I'm not in the context of the event by the time I know if I need to cancel the selection or not.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the top thread, there is an official way to implement what I think you want in DOM. What you can use in lieu of events is something called a range object.

Consider, (which works definitively on FF3)

```
window.onclick = function(evt)
{
   // retrieves the selection and displays its content
   var selectObj = window.getSelection();
   alert(selectObj);

   // now collapse the selection to the initial point of the selection
   var rangeObj = selectObj.getRangeAt(0);
   rangeObj.collapse(true);
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite fly with IE, Opera, Chrome, or Safari; not sure why, because in Opera, Chrome, or Safari, there is something associated with the collapse and getRangeAt methods. If I know more, I'll let you know.

---

An update on my previous answer, one that works more universally is the selection object and collapse, collapseToStart, collapseToEnd methods. ([link text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection#Properties))

Now consider the 2.0 of the above:

```
window.onmouseup = function(evt)
{
   var selectObj = window.getSelection();
   alert(selectObj); // to get a flavor of what you selected

   // works in FF3, Safari, Opera, and Chrome
   selectObj.collapseToStart();

   // works in FF3, Safari, Chrome (but not opera)
   /* selectObj.collapse(document.body, 0); */

   // and as the code is native, I have no idea why...
   // ...and it makes me sad
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will help, exactly, but here is some code to de-select text:

```
// onselectstart is IE-only
if ('undefined' !== typeof this.onselectstart) {
    this.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
} else {
    this.onmousedown   = function () { return false; };
    this.onclick       = function () { return true;  };
}
```

"this" in this context would be the element for which you want to prevent text selections.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).focus()` (or anything along the lines of `document.body.focus()`) seems to do the trick, although I haven't tested it much beyond ff3.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this question works for me:
  [How to disable text selection using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700029/694469)

(It not only disables, but also *cancels*, any text selection.
At least on my computer in FF and Chrome.)

Here is what the answer does:

```
    .attr('unselectable', 'on')

    '-ms-user-select': 'none',
    '-moz-user-select': 'none',
    '-webkit-user-select': 'none',
    'user-select': 'none'

    .each(function() {  // for IE
      this.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to knight for the beginnings of a universal solution.  This slight modification also includes support for IE 7-10 (and probably 6).

I had a similar prob as cwillu-gmail.. needed to attach to the shift-click event (click on label while holding shift key) to perform some alternate functionality when in a specific "design" mode. (Yeah, sounds weird, but it's what the client wanted.) That part was easy, but had the annoying effect of selecting text. This worked for me: (I used onclick but you could use onmouseup.. depends on what you are trying to do and when)

```
var element = document.getElementById("myElementId");
element.onclick = function (event)
{
    // if (event.shiftKey) // uncomment this line to only deselect text when clicking while holding shift key
    {
        if (document.selection)
        {
            document.selection.empty(); // works in IE (7/8/9/10)
        }
        else if (window.getSelection)
        {
            window.getSelection().collapseToStart(); // works in chrome/safari/opera/FF
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `window.getSelection().collapseToStart()` runs but doesn't seem to cancel selection in Chrome anymore...