# How to disable text selection using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Does jQuery or jQuery-UI have any functionality to disable text selection for given document elements?

Comment: *Possible* duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319126/prevent-highlight-of-text

Comment: @John: Does the link above answer your question? If it does not, you might want to throw in some more detail as to how your situation is different.

Comment: Yes it does. But although the answer is the same, that question is very specific so many can miss that answer having in mind more general question (as I did).

Comment: @Jhon: The other question has a jQuery solution too.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

In jQuery 1.8, this can be done as follows:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.disableSelection = function() {
        return this
                 .attr('unselectable', 'on')
                 .css('user-select', 'none')
                 .on('selectstart', false);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The JavaScript alternative works only for IE. "onselectstart" is not available for other browsers

Comment: @Omar: I'm well aware of that.

Comment: Unfortunately they can still do a select all (through menu or key combpo) and get a selection (in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox AFAIK). Do you know of a solution to this? I am sure I can grab the keypress and return false in case of CTRL-C or CTRL-A but that does not help if they use the browser menu to select text. So far my only thoughts on a solution to this is to embed the text inside a Flash object.

Comment: @Bryce: Just don't.  http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/on-copy-prevention-in-html-part-2.html  http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/on-copy-prevention-in-html-part-3.html

Comment: @SLaks: Nice! Thanks for that jolt of inspiration. Based on the inflate method I can easily write up a solution that will foil non-programmers. Your other solutions are overkill for my problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was working on a dragging slider and needed a way that text wouldn't be selected in the process.

Comment: Thank you. I'm surprised this isn't done for [jQuery UI buttons](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/radio.html). I accidentally selected text instead of clicking the button several times.

Comment: jQuery UI buttons not implementing this, specifically on buttonsets, is disappointing.

Comment: @SLaks how would your then re-enable?

Comment: @SkylarSaveland: Reverse each of those settings.

Comment: @SLaks: This answer should include `.css('MozUserSelect','none')` to cover Firefox.

Comment: @Mottie: Wrong; jQuery does that automatically.  See the edit history.

Comment: @SLaks: correct, I should have said, jQuery older than v1.8 needs the `.css('MozUserSelect', 'none')` for it to work in Firefox.

Comment: To those of you who say "just don't" to disabling text selection (or anything else on SO for that matter),  open thy minds just a bit. Often times people disable it for aesthetic reasons such as avoiding text selection on a double click of a label with text in it, etc.
So either answer the question, or provide an actual counter point and specify what you're talking about negating, don't just scratch the idea out in a general manner.

Comment: @SLaks's answer is exactly how jQuery UI Core lib provided the API `disableSelection` http://api.jqueryui.com/disableSelection/ However, it's a short lived feature. jQuery UI core removed it since v1.9 (was added at v1.6).

Comment: Sorry for asking, but how can I select my specific element? I want to select this: `#idname`

Comment: @stack This creates a new "disableSelection" method that you can use. So you can call it like:  $("#idname").disableSelection();

Comment: I am using the disable body selection prior to dynamically adding and displaying a modal window.  

What code would be used restore selectability after the window is closed?

Comment: @Richard: Just remove / unbind each of these.

Answer (score 101):

If you use jQuery UI, there is a method for that, but it can only handle mouse selection (i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is still working):

```
$('.your-element').disableSelection(); // deprecated in jQuery UI 1.9
```

The code is realy simple, if you don't want to use jQuery UI :

```
$(el).attr('unselectable','on')
     .css({'-moz-user-select':'-moz-none',
           '-moz-user-select':'none',
           '-o-user-select':'none',
           '-khtml-user-select':'none', /* you could also put this in a class */
           '-webkit-user-select':'none',/* and add the CSS class here instead */
           '-ms-user-select':'none',
           'user-select':'none'
     }).bind('selectstart', function(){ return false; });
```

Comment: the jquery ui function would be great, but it doesn't offer the same level of protection, it does prevent selecting things directly, but if you're carrying a selection from another dom object, you need the css rules too - 

heres the function =

function () {
  return this.bind( ( $.support.selectstart ? "selectstart" : "mousedown" ) +
   ".ui-disableSelection", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
   });
 }

Comment: Note that disableSelection() is deprecated in jQuery UI 1.9

Comment: It could also require .on('mousedown', false) to work, depending on your browser. Hovewer, it's dangerous to kill mousedown events on by default because this could probably brake existing functionality

Comment: Arg. It's annoying it's been depreciated. There's plenty of time when you want this legitimately.

Comment: I'm creating a right-click context menu on some anchor text, and I don't want the text to select on click. So yes, @Monk, this would qualify as a legitimate example.

Comment: do we still need to include vendor prefixes in jquery `.css()`?

Answer (score 76):

I found this answer ( [Prevent Highlight of Text Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319126/prevent-highlight-of-text/1319158#1319158) ) most helpful, and perhaps it can be combined with another way of providing IE compatibility.

```
#yourTable
{
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Chrome uses -webkit-user-select

Comment: Always appreciate the CSS way to do things instead of using jQuery or JS in general. Just like jQuery animations vs CSS transitions, the way built into the browser is always going to be the best and most efficient.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a more comprehensive solution to the disconnect selection, and the cancellation of some of the hot keys (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. [Test:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript)  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>)

```
(function($){

  $.fn.ctrlCmd = function(key) {

    var allowDefault = true;

    if (!$.isArray(key)) {
       key = [key];
    }

    return this.keydown(function(e) {
        for (var i = 0, l = key.length; i < l; i++) {
            if(e.keyCode === key[i].toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) && e.metaKey) {
                allowDefault = false;
            }
        };
        return allowDefault;
    });
};


$.fn.disableSelection = function() {

    this.ctrlCmd(['a', 'c']);

    return this.attr('unselectable', 'on')
               .css({'-moz-user-select':'-moz-none',
                     '-moz-user-select':'none',
                     '-o-user-select':'none',
                     '-khtml-user-select':'none',
                     '-webkit-user-select':'none',
                     '-ms-user-select':'none',
                     'user-select':'none'})
               .bind('selectstart', false);
};

})(jQuery);
```

and call example:

```
$(':not(input,select,textarea)').disableSelection();
```

[jsfiddle.net/JBxnQ/](http://jsfiddle.net/JBxnQ/)

This could be also not enough for old versions of FireFox (I can't tell which). If all this does not work, add the following:

```
.on('mousedown', false)
```

Comment: Why do you call `attr('unselectable', 'on')` twice? Is it a typo or is it useful?

Comment: This worked great for me, but I had to disable the ".each(function() {
                    $(this).attr('unselectable','on')
                    .bind('selectstart',function(){ return false; });
               });" section for my particular web app (JQuery Mobile), just in case it helps anyone..

Answer (score 14):

The following would disable the selection of all classes 'item' in all common browsers (IE, Chrome, Mozilla, Opera and Safari):

```
$(".item")
        .attr('unselectable', 'on')
        .css({
            'user-select': 'none',
            'MozUserSelect': 'none'
        })
        .on('selectstart', false)
        .on('mousedown', false);
```

Comment: Not complicated - Excellent! Thank you. For disabled looking; I addded .attr('disabled', 'disabled')

Comment: Update: instead of .attr('disabled', 'disabled'), I used   .attr('readonly', 'readonly'). Disabled prevents posting my model variable in MVC(model variable is null). Readonly still have disabled looking(I use bootstrap) and it allows posting the item value

Comment: Excellent bro, i using this code to replace "pointer-events: none;", that not work in IE 11. regards

Answer (score 7):

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("body").css("-webkit-user-select","none");
            $("body").css("-moz-user-select","none");
            $("body").css("-ms-user-select","none");
            $("body").css("-o-user-select","none");
            $("body").css("user-select","none");
        });
```

Comment: Could you write a brief summary of the answer in addition to the code?

Answer (score 7):

This is actually very simple.
To disable text selection (and also click+drag-ing text (e.g a link in Chrome)), just use the following jQuery code:

```
$('body, html').mousedown(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

All this does is prevent the default from happening when you click with your mouse (`mousedown()`) in the `body` and `html` tags. You can very easily change the element just by changing the text in-between the two quotes (e.g change `$('body, html')` to `$('#myUnselectableDiv')` to make the `myUnselectableDiv` div to be, well, unselectable.

A quick snippet to show/prove this to you:

```js
$('#no-select').mousedown(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="no-select">I bet you can't select this text, or drag <a href="#">this link</a>, </span>
<br/><span>but that you can select this text, and drag <a href="#">this link</a>!</span>
```

Please note that this effect is not perfect, and performs the best while making the whole window not selectable. You might also want to add

> the cancellation of some of the hot keys (such as <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd>. [Test:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript) <kbd>Cmd+a</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd+c</kbd>)

as well, by using that section of Vladimir's answer above. (get to his post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7254601/2518552))

Answer (score 6):

***This can easily be done using JavaScript This is applicable to all Browsers***

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Disable Text Selection script- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

function disableSelection(target){
if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined") //For IE 
    target.onselectstart=function(){return false}
else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined") //For Firefox
    target.style.MozUserSelect="none"
else //All other route (For Opera)
    target.onmousedown=function(){return false}
target.style.cursor = "default"
}
 </script>
```

***Call to this function***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   disableSelection(document.body)
</script>
```

Comment: This one is great! But how do we stop the "focus" on it?

Comment: This answer is outdated by 2013

Answer (score 4):

I've tried all the approaches, and this one is the simplest for me because I'm using IWebBrowser2 and don't have 10 browsers to contend with:

```
document.onselectstart = new Function('return false;');
```

Works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 1):

1 line solution for CHROME:

```
body.style.webkitUserSelect = "none";
```

and FF:

```
body.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
```

IE requires setting the "unselectable" attribute (details on bottom).

I tested this in Chrome and it works. This property is inherited so setting it on the body element will disable selection in your entire document.

Details here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljrlukea.php

If you're using Closure, just call this function:

```
goog.style.setUnselectable(myElement, true);
```

It handles all browsers transparently.

The non-IE browsers are handled like this:

```
goog.style.unselectableStyle_ =
    goog.userAgent.GECKO ? 'MozUserSelect' :
    goog.userAgent.WEBKIT ? 'WebkitUserSelect' :
    null;
```

Defined here:
http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/!svn/bc/4/trunk/closure/goog/docs/closure_goog_style_style.js.source.html

The IE portion is handled like this:

```
if (goog.userAgent.IE || goog.userAgent.OPERA) {
// Toggle the 'unselectable' attribute on the element and its descendants.
var value = unselectable ? 'on' : '';
el.setAttribute('unselectable', value);
if (descendants) {
  for (var i = 0, descendant; descendant = descendants[i]; i++) {
    descendant.setAttribute('unselectable', value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code **works on all browsers** and requires the least overhead. It's really a hybrid of all the above answers. Let me know if you find a bug!

**Add CSS:**

```
.no_select { user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select:none;}
```

**Add jQuery:**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.disableSelection = function() 
    {       
        $(this).addClass('no_select');              
        if($.browser.msie)
        {
            $(this).attr('unselectable', 'on').on('selectstart', false);            
        }
    return this;            
};
})(jQuery);
```

Optional: To disable selection for all children elements as well, you can change the IE block to:

```
$(this).each(function() {
    $(this).attr('unselectable','on')
    .bind('selectstart',function(){ return false; });
});
```

**Usage:**

```
$('.someclasshere').disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this, for appropriate cases, is to use a `<button>` for the text that you don't want to be selectable. If you are binding to the `click` event on some text block, and don't want that text to be selectable, changing it to be a button will improve the semantics and also prevent the text being selected.

```
<button>Text Here</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Best and simplest way I found it, prevents ctrl + c, right click. In this case I blocked everything, so I don't have to specify anything.

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu cut copy",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert('Copying is not allowed');
});
```