# How does one capture a Mac's command key via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How does one capture a Mac's <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key via JavaScript?

Comment: Use this https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster

Comment: There is a javascript-lib for that: [keymaster.js](https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster) (no dependencies like jquery)

Answer (score 339, accepted):

**EDIT:** As of 2019, `e.metaKey` is [supported on all major browsers as per the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey).

Note that on Windows, although the <kbd>⊞ Windows</kbd> key is considered to be the "meta" key, it is not going to be captured by browsers as such.

This is only for the command key on MacOS/keyboards.

---

Unlike <kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> (“Apple”) key is not considered a modifier key—instead, you should listen on `keydown`/`keyup` and record when a key is pressed and then depressed based on `event.keyCode`.

Unfortunately, these key codes are browser-dependent:

- Firefox: `224`
- Opera: `17`
- WebKit browsers (Safari/Chrome): `91` (Left Command) or `93` (Right Command)

You might be interested in reading the article [JavaScript Madness: Keyboard Events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html), from which I learned that knowledge.

Comment: Know that Opera is now also under the Webkit category. I think just listening for 91, 93, and 224, will get the job done. 17 is Ctrl, by the way. Did old Opera not differentiate Cmd and Ctrl??

Comment: It seems that event.metaKey works in the current versions of Safari, Firefox and Chrome like a charm. IMO it is much clear solution.

Comment: In response to Miroslav's comment, just note that it only works on **`keydown`** events, not `keyup`.

Comment: In response to @nachocab 's comment: e.key === 'Meta' works for both keydown and keyup. So this can be used instead of e.metaKey

Comment: @nachocab You helped me a lot with comment about keydown / keyup . Because I was stuck in keypress event not understanding, what is wrong with it))

Answer (score 235):

You can also look at the `event.metaKey` attribute on the event if you are working with `keydown` events. Worked wonderfully for me! [You can try it here](https://jsbin.com/cinojahoyu/edit?js,output).

Comment: That doesn't seem to be set for me with Firefox 4.0.1 on MacOS. Given that the accepted answer and the linked reference both disagree with what you've said as well, I think this answer is incorrect.

Comment: The accepted answer gives another, more painful, way to make it work, while the linked reference says that "According to the DOM 3 standard, on the Macintosh, the Option key should activate event.altKey and the Command key should activate event.metaKey. These attributes seem to work correctly on all modern browsers tested" ! The answer works for me under Firefox 5.0 on MacOS. I'll try and test it in older versions.

Comment: Also, the accepted answer wrongly says that "Mac/Apple key is not considered as a modifier key", even though the given reference says the contrary ! [Here is a script](http://edit.sunfox.org/metakey.html) that shows the `.metaKey` modifier working under Mac Firefox 3.6.3 -> 5.0.

Comment: `.metaKey` indeed works in latest Firefox, Safari and Opera. In Chrome, `.metaKey` triggers on Control (not on Command).

Comment: FWIW, cmd+e doesn't work for me in your script. Ctrl triggers the CMD icon you have

Comment: cmd+e doesn't fire the event for me either (chrome). ctrl+e does.

Comment: I think the trick (even in Chrome) is that this works for `keydown` but NOT for `keyup` or `keypress`.

Comment: You are right @philfreo, tested here in Chrome. I updated the answer and [the example](http://edit.sunfox.org/metakey.html) accordingly.

Comment: You might want to add a call to event.preventDefault() to prevent the browser and/or OS from processing the command key.

Answer (score 18):

I found that you can detect the command key in the latest version of Safari (7.0: 9537.71) if it is pressed in conjunction with another key. For example, if you want to detect ⌘+x:, you can detect the x key AND check if event.metaKey is set to true. For example:

```
var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode || 0;
console.log(key, event.metaKey);
```

When pressing x on it's own, this will output `120, false`. When pressing ⌘+x, it will output `120, true`

This only seems to work in Safari - not Chrome

Comment: what is the status in 2017?

Answer (score 16):

Basing on Ilya's data, I wrote a Vanilla JS library for supporting modifier keys on Mac: https://github.com/MichaelZelensky/jsLibraries/blob/master/macKeys.js

Just use it like this, e.g.:

```
document.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.shiftKey || macKeys.shiftKey) {
    //do something interesting
  }
}
```

Tested on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera on Mac. Please check if it works for you.

Answer (score 9):

`keyCode` and `which` are now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keycode) so it's advisable to avoid the answers that use those here.

One way to do this now is using the `key` property on the event argument that comes with DOM `keyup` and `keypress` events. Here's a simple example of how to do it:

```
document.onkeypress = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Meta') {
        console.log("Mac or Windows key was pressed!");
    } else {
        console.log("Another key was pressed")
    }
}
```

This will trigger on the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key press on Mac ([See Meta on the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values)). The only thing to note here is it will also trigger on the Windows key press too for the users keyboard/OS that support it.

If you need more granular understanding of which Meta key has been pressed, you can use the `code` property on event which can be either [`MetaLeft` or `MetaRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code/code_values) depending on which physical meta key ( <kbd>cmd</kbd>) was pressed.

Answer (score 7):

For people using jQuery, there is an excellent plugin for handling key events:

[jQuery hotkeys on GitHub](https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys)

For capturing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> I'm using this:

```
$(window).bind('keydown.ctrl_s keydown.meta_s', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Do something here
});
```

Comment: Works too well. All other key presses get captured too.

Comment: Is it cross browser supported?

Comment: If you visited the link in my answer, you would've known: https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys#jquery-compatibility

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did it in AngularJS

```coffee
app = angular.module('MM_Graph')

class Keyboard
  constructor: ($injector)->
    @.$injector  = $injector
    @.$window    = @.$injector.get('$window')                             # get reference to $window and $rootScope objects
    @.$rootScope = @.$injector.get('$rootScope')

  on_Key_Down:($event)=>
    @.$rootScope.$broadcast 'keydown', $event                             # broadcast a global keydown event

    if $event.code is 'KeyS' and ($event.ctrlKey or $event.metaKey)       # detect S key pressed and either OSX Command or Window's Control keys pressed
      @.$rootScope.$broadcast '', $event                                  # broadcast keyup_CtrS event
      #$event.preventDefault()                                             # this should be used by the event listeners to prevent default browser behaviour

  setup_Hooks: ()=>
    angular.element(@.$window).bind "keydown", @.on_Key_Down              # hook keydown event in window (only called once per app load)
    @

app.service 'keyboard', ($injector)=>
  return new Keyboard($injector).setup_Hooks()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var element = //the DOM element to listen for the key on.
element.onkeyup = function(e) {
   if(e.metaKey) {
      //command key was pressed
   }
}
```

Comment: var element = document.body; 
element.onKeyUp = function(e) {
   if(e.metaKey) {
      console.log('cmd pressed')
   }
}

Answer (score 1):

With a `KeyboardEvent.metaKey: boolean`

```
fromEvent(window, 'keydown').pipe(takeUntil(this._ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(
  (res: KeyboardEvent) => {
    console.log(res.metaKey && res.key === 'Enter');
  }
);
```

This example is for RxJS' fromEvent but applies to any KeyboardEvent.

Answer (score 0):

This show capture the mac command and windows ctrl

#Mac command

```
$("#my_input").on('change keyup input', function() {
    var e = window.event || e; var key = e.keyCode; if(key == 93) {
        alert("Hello");
}
});
```

#Windows ctrl

```
$("#my_input").on('change keyup input', function() {
    var e = window.event || e; var key = e.keyCode; if(key == 17) {
        alert("Hello");
}
});
```

#Both

```
$("#my_input").on('change keyup input', function() {
    var e = window.event || e; var key = e.keyCode; if(key == 17 || key == 93) {
        alert("Hello");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if((e.key == 'Meta' && /Mac OS/.test(navigator.userAgent)) || e.ctrlKey) {
      // CTRL or CMD pressed
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use Vuejs, just make it by vue-shortkey plugin, everything will be simple

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-shortkey

```
v-shortkey="['meta', 'enter']"·
@shortkey="metaEnterTrigged"
```