# Will this hotkey work for Mac users?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome-extension, hotkeys

I'm using the following code to catch when people press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for my chrome extension:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  var modifier = event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey;
  if (modifier && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 80) {
    //code goes here
  }
});
```

I'm hoping the `var modifier = event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey;` line means it will catch when Mac users press Cmd-Shift-P but have no Mac computer to test this on. Is it so? Will my hotkey work for Mac users?

Also, what is the keyCode for when the Cmd key goes down and up? Is it 17, the same as for Ctrl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keycodes differ in different browsers. Here you can find more information on the subject:
[How does one capture a Mac's command key via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript)

On my mac in Chrome I get the keycode 91 but it will differ, in the linked post these are mentioned:
Firefox: 224
Opera: 17
WebKit (Safari/Chrome): 91 (Left Apple) or 93 (Right Apple)

There is also a link to this page which tells all about it:
http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Your code does work in Chrome on Mac (pressing the <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).