# event on shift+option+command+left click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using javascript (jquery okay), how could I fire an event on a shift+option+command+left click on an object?

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
        if( e.keyCode == 224 && e.keyCode == 16 && e.keyCode == 18 ){
               console.log('keys pressed');
        }
});
```

It seems like something like this should work for logging the keys (but it doesn't at all ^^ ) And also, how do I track the click?

Thanks!

Comment: If the `keyCode` is `224`, it can't be `16` or `18`. inspect the event object `e` for properties that refer to the modifier keys you are looking for.

Comment: @thomas I am on windows can you please tell me what's the option and command keycodes? btw when you refer to Left you mean the left arrow right?

Comment: @OscarJara No that should be left-click. mouse button. I'm looking for those keycodes now

Comment: Ok, I will wait for the keycodes... Well, I assume that you want to detect just the click (same as left-click) right?

Comment: @OscarJara yeah, I can't find them. Or, I mean, the ones I do, none seem to work.. Thanks -

Comment: @thomas for example e.keyCode == 16 means SHIFT I need to know e.keyCode == 224 is for? and e.keyCode == 18?

Comment: This answer will give you some start http://stackoverflow.com/q/3902635/1331430

Comment: @OscarJara oh, right! is is 91, not 224

Comment: @FabrícioMatté thanks! I looked at this wrong the first time ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Live Demo** *(for Mac OS)*: http://jsfiddle.net/NDuDZ/2/

Code:

```
//Combination: Shift+Option+Command+LeftClick

//Shift Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera keyCode: 16
//Option Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera keyCode: 18
//Command Firefox keyCode: 224
//Command Chrome, Safari keyCode: 91
//Command Opera keyCode: 17

var isOption = false;
var isCommand = false;
var isLeftClick = false;

$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.which == 91 || e.which == 224 || e.which == 17) isCommand = false;
    if(e.which == 18) isOption = false;
});

$(document).on('click', function(e){
    isLeftClick = true;
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.which == 91 || e.which == 224 || e.which == 17) isCommand = true;
    if(e.which == 18) isOption = true;
    if(e.which == 16 && isOption && isCommand && isLeftClick) {
       alert('Shift+Option+Command+LeftClick invoked!');
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: it works pretty well. thank you. I do notice that after you click once, every time you do the `ctl+opt+cmd` afterward the alert is triggered. also the even fires when the keys are released. is there anyway to fire it on the mouse click. it's totally brilliant by the way; thanks much!

Comment: @thomas yes, I noticed that after I posted my answer, I tried to do an improved version but no success (also I am on Windows) and this is the best I can do by now. You can play with that code and maybe do something better because everything is done I think :-)