# How to get Alt + C(or any other key) to work in JavaScript on Chrome for Mac and windows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have tried following code,

```
window.onkeypress =  function(event){

   if(event.altKey && (event.keyCode == 99 || event.keyCode == 67)){

      alert("alt + C pressed")
   }
}
```

How ever It doesn't work!

I tried alert(event.keyCode) per keypress and it seems when I press opt/alt key on Mac, I get a different keycode other than 99 or 67 with the combination.

Whats the correct way to achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one capture a Mac's command key via Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript)

Comment: I have seen and tried that example. command key is working fine. I have a problem with alt!

Comment: Got it, on Mac option plus other key combination generates different characters that's why!

opt + c prints ç on TextEdit, thats why a different keyCode.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `keydown` or `keyup` handler. In that case 'c' = `keyCode` 67:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || event;
    if (e.altKey && e.keyCode === 67) {
        console.log("alt+c pressed!");
    }
}​
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/c7NNy/)

Comment: Doesn't work on the iMac keyboard. Option + key is generating a different character and keyCode value wont remain 67 or 99!

Comment: I wanted to launch a popup with that key combination, I think I will resort to cmd + shift + c instead!

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript offers a solution?