# Key Codes for apple in GWT

Tags: macos, gwt

I need to catch the combination of `Apple + C` in GWT `NativePreviewHandler`

Here is the code that use to catch `CTRL + C` and it works:

```java
nativeEventsHandlerRegistration = Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(Event.NativePreviewEvent event) {

        NativeEvent nativeEvent = event.getNativeEvent();

        if (Event.getTypeInt(nativeEvent.getType()) == Event.ONKEYDOWN) {
            if (nativeEvent.getCtrlKey() && 'C' == nativeEvent.getKeyCode()) {      
                // do something
            }
        }

    }

});
```

I need the same thing but for MAC, any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript

Comment: @GWT4Ever You can post that as answer. Seems a valid answer to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was already a discussion very similar to yours at stackoverflow go check it out:

[How does one capture a Mac's command key via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript)

Comment: Yep, saw it in the comment. Thanks, this is very helpful.