# How to detect command key is pressed in javascript at mac os

Tags: javascript

I am working with ctrl+c and ctrl+v event in javascript i want to bind a function on ctrl+v event. and i am able to do it with event.keyCode  in windows system but in mac os on command press i am not able to figure out the event. 
My code is

```
 $('.hindi_content').keyup(function(event){

        console.log('UP'+event.keyCode);

       console.log('in window::'+ event.ctrlKey+'in mac os'+event.metaKey+'####'+event.META_MASK+'##$&&'+event.CTRL_MASK);

      //  this is  working with windows not with mac os. 
       if(event.keyCode==86 && event.ctrlKey)
        {
            console.log('ctrl press'+event.ctrlKey);

            col_val = $('#'+this.id).val();
            console.log('col val'+col_val);

            $('#hidden_'+this.id).val(col_val);
            console.log('hidden val'+ $('#hidden_'+this.id).val());
            //converter_new(event,this.lang);
            // return;
        }
```

});

i search and found event.metaKey but it is for ctrl key in mac i just want command key in mac os.

Answer (score 4):

Things seem to have gotten easier since this question was first asked.  I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript) which states that `event.metaKey` will work for `cmd` on mac.  I just tested it and it works fine.

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
   var key = event.key;
   var cmd_held = event.metaKey;

   if(cmd_held && key.toLowerCase() == "v") 
       pasta();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

mousetrap is a library that makes those things really easy:

http://craig.is/killing/mice

```
//control + v
Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+v', function(e) {
    //do things here
});

//command + k & control +v
Mousetrap.bind(['command+v', 'ctrl+v'], function(e) {
    //do things here
});
```

Comment: An example of how "mousetrap" would be applied towards the question would be appreciated (yes, I know that there are a few on that page, but generally the answer should contain everything needed to complete the task).

Answer (score 0):

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dexterity/3oqtyhur/)

```
Individual detect<br>
<input id="myinput" placeholder="Click command key on your mac"><br>
<div class="output" id="output"></div><br><br>
right or left detect<br>
<input id="myinput2" placeholder="Click command key on your mac"><br><br>
<div class="output" id="output2"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('keydown', '#myinput', function() {
  if (event.keyCode == '91') {
    $("#output").empty().append("left command clicked");
  }

  if (event.keyCode == '93') {
    $("#output").empty().append("right command clicked");
  }
});

$(document).on('keydown', '#myinput2', function() {
  if (event.keyCode == '91' || event.keyCode == '93') {
    $("#output2").empty().append("right or left command clicked");
  }
});

$("input").on('blur', function() {
  $(".output").empty();
});
</script>
```