# get ctrl-f/ctrl-a keypresses in node-webkit

Tags: javascript, binding, keypress, node-webkit

I'm building a node-webkit app, am listening for keypress events (in an angular directive).

Most combinations of keypress are working, but <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> are both not working.

This problem is specific to node-webkit. I've got the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> etc. working in the browser, but not in node-webkit.

I'm listening for keypress with the usual

```
document.bind('keypress',function...)

window.bind('keypress', function...)

window.bind('onkeypress', function...)

window.bind('keydown', function...)
```

any suggestions? Remember, the other combinations of keys <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, etc. are working.
As this is a node-webkit app, there is no browser based 'find' function, and I'm disabling the 'select all'.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202110/kill-default-ctrl-f-search-bar-in-firefox-internet-explorer) an answer you where looking for?

There is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/ujJ75/) in answer of ctrl+f. If you replace 70 to 65 in this example, it will also work for ctrl+a.

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {

    /// check ctrl + f key
    if (e.ctrlKey === true && e.keyCode === 70/*65*/) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log('Ctrl + f was hit...');

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is specific to node-webkit. Even if I don't look for e.ctrlKey and just console.log(e) on ctrl-a, the keydown isn't triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library you can use to add `ctrl+f` "find" support in NW.js.

- https://github.com/nwutils/find-in-nw

`ctrl+a` to "select all" is already built in to Normal and SDK versions of NW.js

However, if you want to override the default "ctrl+a", then Andrew's answer is correct and will do that. Listen for the event and prevent default.