# How to detect pressed keys on the click of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, keypress

I'm using angularjs on a web application that I need to figure out how can I detect is keys like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd> are pressed when I click somewhere.

For example, with jQuery I can do that by accessing the Click function arguments.

Is there some out-of-the-box way to obtain that information on angular?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at this beautiful Stuff regarding [AngularJS key handling](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/eventhandlers/keyboardevents/)

So key code for Ctrl, shift, alt will be

**Ctrl - 17

Alt - 18

Shift - 16**

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/huzimesu/4/)**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="mainModule">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <label>Type something:
      <input type="text"
             ng-keydown="onKeyDown($event)"
             ng-keyup="onKeyUp($event)"
             ng-keypress="onKeyPress($event)" />
    </label><br />
    <strong>KEY DOWN RESULT:</strong> {{onKeyDownResult}}<br />
    <strong>KEY UP RESULT:</strong> {{onKeyUpResult}}<br />
    <strong>KEY PRESS RESULT:</strong> {{onKeyPressResult}}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
angular.module("mainModule", [])
  .controller("mainController", function ($scope)
  {
    // Initialization
    $scope.onKeyDownResult = "";
    $scope.onKeyUpResult = "";
    $scope.onKeyPressResult = "";

    // Utility functions

    var getKeyboardEventResult = function (keyEvent, keyEventDesc)
    {
      return keyEventDesc + " (keyCode: " + (window.event ? keyEvent.keyCode : keyEvent.which) + ")";
    };

    // Event handlers
    $scope.onKeyDown = function ($event) {
      $scope.onKeyDownResult = getKeyboardEventResult($event, "Key down");
    };

    $scope.onKeyUp = function ($event) {
      $scope.onKeyUpResult = getKeyboardEventResult($event, "Key up");
    };

    $scope.onKeyPress = function ($event) {
      $scope.onKeyPressResult = getKeyboardEventResult($event, "Key press");
    };
  });
```

Comment: Perfect, that it, working perfectly, just have to add $event. Thanks

Answer (score 36):

In your html

```
<button ng-click="doSomething($event)"></button>
```

In your js

```
$scope.doSomething = function($event)
{
if ($event.altKey){}
if ($event.ctrlKey){}
if ($event.shiftKey){}
}
```

Comment: Much simpler than all other alternatives. Worked perfectly when I needed to check the Ctrl key

Comment: Note: ctrlKey will not work as expected on mac, as this triggers a context menu. Mac uses the command key for this.

Comment: @PMBjornerud how do you detect the command key then. can you post a code snippet or something. thanks

Comment: I don't have the code I used at the moment. Maybe here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript

Comment: Can we do this with ng-change, my ng-change is detecting a change, but with that I want to check if the ng-change is triggered with ctrl key clicked, so that I can open in new tab.

Answer (score 6):

There is no "automated" way using pure JS, but it's relatively simple to track modifier keys' state in global variables. E.g.

```
window.ctrlDown = false;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
  var e = window.event || evt;
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if(17 == key) {
    window.ctrlDown = true;
  }
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
  var e = window.event || evt;
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if(17 == key) {
    window.ctrlDown = false;
  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to capture a key combination, such as Ctrl-Enter, you can look at the window object

For example to find Ctrl-Enter use

```
if(window.event.keyCode == 13 && window.event.ctrlKey == true)
```

Comment: For angular you should use `$event` instead of `window.event`.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm not sure what each browser provides, I would do it this way:

```
shiftPressed = event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode === 16);
```

On Chorme for example I can't see any event.keyCode on the click event:

```
altKey: false
bubbles: true
button: 0
buttons: 0
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: true
clientX: 753
clientY: 193
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
detail: 1
eventPhase: 0
fromElement: null
isDefaultPrevented: ()
isImmediatePropagationStopped: ()
isTrusted: true
isTrusted: true
layerX: 4
layerY: -15
metaKey: false
movementX: 0
movementY: 0
offsetX: 4
offsetY: -15
pageX: 1381
pageY: 193
path: Array[16]
relatedTarget: null
returnValue: true
screenX: 753
screenY: 278
shiftKey: true
srcElement: span.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus
stopImmediatePropagation: ()
target: span.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus
timeStamp: 1445613423528
toElement: span.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus
type: "click"
view: Window
webkitMovementX: 0
webkitMovementY: 0
which: 1
x: 753
y: 193
```