# how to get keychar on continuous keydown event - angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a custom dropdown in angular JS which is a combination of textbox and list. Here on keydown event I am checking the key code and getting the char from `String.fromCharCode(keyCode)`. and apply the style(highlighted) for the typed character from the list. This works fine for a single character.

for example in my list iam having `{'india','ireland','egypt','england','nigeria'}`

Here my code works if I type `e` it will point to the first country Egypt. My requirement is if I type `en` continuously it should highlight England, but this is not happening. As soon as I type `n` it will highlight Nigeria. because the keydown event is immediately firing and it is selecting for next char entered.

```
elem.on('keydown.ddl', function (e) {

    case (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90):

        var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(keyCode); //this give
        //here i am changing the style
        break;
});
```

Comment: can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: unfortunately i dont have access to jsFiddle

Comment: Why don't you use directly the value in your textbox?

Comment: together text box and list should function like a dropdown. until i press enter key the textbox should be null

Comment: Here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651954/how-to-detect-pressed-keys-on-the-click-of-angularjs