# cmd+c in keyUp event on Chrome OSX (Mac)

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, dom-events

I am looking to detect <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in the `keyUp` event in Chrome OSX. I need a plain Javascript solution not relaying on external libraries.

I found this [How does one capture a Mac's command key via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript) but there is no clear solution to my requirements above..

If this can't be done, second best is to detect it in `keyDown` Chrome OSX.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not specifically looking for full coverage of <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>any</kbd> you could cheat a little bit and use the [`ClipboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent) API. MDN flags it as *"experimental"* but it seems to be supported by all major browsers - in any case it works in Chrome on Mac if that's what you're targeting.

Instead of listening for the `keyup` event you could just listen for `copy`:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('myElement');
el.addEventListener('copy', function(evt){
    console.log('Cmd+C pressed');
});
```

The caveat being: this will also fire on any event that alters the clipboard - such as selecting copy from a right-click context menu (though this may equally be desirable depending on your intent).