# D3 change zoom and pan gestures

Tags: d3.js

Out of the box, D3 V4 pan and zoom work perfectly for me using the following code:

```typescript
const zoom = d3.zoom();
zoom.on("zoom", () => this.zoom());
this._svg.call(zoom);

zoom()
{
    this._svg_g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

Where _svg is an svg element and _svg_g is a top level g element within the svg.

However, what I would like to do is to associate the behavior with gestures that are different from the defaults.

I would like the behavior as follows:

**Zoom**

- As currently with the mouse wheel, but only when Ctrl key is pressed.
- On particular key presses (e.g. Ctrl+= or Ctrl+-).

**Pan**

- As currently but only when Alt key is pressed.
- Vertically with the mouse wheel and no modifier keys.
- Horizontally with the mouse wheel when Shift is pressed.

The exact gestures are subject to change, but the essential elements are:

- Enable zooming and panning only under certain conditions (e.g. modifier key pressed)
- Trigger zooming and panning on events of my choosing

Answer (score 4):

You could use the filter function:

```html
d3.zoom()
    .filter(() => {
      if (d3.event.type === 'wheel') {
        // don't allow zooming without pressing [ctrl] key
        return d3.event.ctrlKey;
      }

      return true;
    })
    .on('zoom', function () {
       this.zoomed();
    });
```

Comment: How could I do this with the command key for apple computers?

Comment: Command key is `metaKey`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3922353/1121268
Which is available in the d3 event object