# Angular 2+ elegant way to intercept Command+S

Tags: javascript, angular, cross-browser, keyboard-shortcuts, onkeyup

Trying to implement a shortcut key combination for Command+S to save a form.

I've read this - https://angular.io/guide/user-input, but it does not say anything about meta or command.

Tried surrounding the form with:

```
<div
  (keyup.command.s)="save()"
  (keyup.command.u)="save()"
  (keyup.control.u)="save()"
  (keyup.control.s)="save()"
  (keyup.meta.u)="save()"
>
```

Of those, only `control.u` and `control.s` worked.

With all the power and cross-browser capabilities of Angular 2+, I was hoping that this is somehow handled in an elegant way, using `(keyup...)`.

And for sure many Angular Devs use Macs :).

I've also read [How does one capture a Mac's command key via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript) and http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html but still hoping for Angular elegant solution instead of fighting with browser-specific stuff...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **UPDATE**

To stop the save dialog of the browser from opening, we must use the `keydown` event instead of `keyup` and call the function `$event.preventDefault();`. Updated code below:

```
  onKeyDown($event): void {
    // Detect platform
    if(navigator.platform.match('Mac')){
        this.handleMacKeyEvents($event);
    }
    else {
        this.handleWindowsKeyEvents($event); 
    }
  }

  handleMacKeyEvents($event) {
    // MetaKey documentation
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey
    let charCode = String.fromCharCode($event.which).toLowerCase();
    if ($event.metaKey && charCode === 's') {
        // Action on Cmd + S
        $event.preventDefault();
    } 
  }

  handleWindowsKeyEvents($event) {
    let charCode = String.fromCharCode($event.which).toLowerCase();
    if ($event.ctrlKey && charCode === 's') {
        // Action on Ctrl + S
        $event.preventDefault();
    } 
  }
```

Then bind this method to the `(keydown)` event in your div:

```
<div (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)" tabindex="0">
</div>
```

Updated [**PLUNKER DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/qG1gAjPx1AC0GMFQanr2?p=preview)

---

> **ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Here is an idea, how about detecting the event in you class:

```
  onKeyUp($event): void {
    // Detect platform
    if(navigator.platform.match('Mac')){
        this.handleMacKeyEvents($event);
    }
    else {
        this.handleWindowsKeyEvents($event); 
    }
  }

  handleMacKeyEvents($event) {
    // MetaKey documentation
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey
    let charCode = String.fromCharCode($event.which).toLowerCase();
    if ($event.metaKey && charCode === 's') {
        // Action on Cmd + S
        $event.preventDefault();
    } 
  }

  handleWindowsKeyEvents($event) {
    let charCode = String.fromCharCode($event.which).toLowerCase();
    if ($event.ctrlKey && charCode === 's') {
        // Action on Ctrl + S
        $event.preventDefault();
    } 
  }
```

Then bind this method to the `(keyup)` event in your div:

```
<div (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" tabindex="0">
</div>
```

---

Here is a plunker link: [**PLUNKER DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xtaTjKzPwIDXpc77ZcUj?p=preview)

Comment: There is an Boolean for "meta" keys, which is the Command key on mac, it's `event.metaKey`.

Comment: @KarolDepka in mac you have `metaKey`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Tried `$event.metaKey`.  Behaves weirdly. I have not yet managed to capture any useful key combination with `metaKey`... As if it is not a modifier key (which I've read somewhere as well...)

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc: have you managed to capture actual meta+letter key combinations using `metaKey`?

Comment: here is a useful article on key combinations: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3088-native-key-combination-event-binding-support-in-angular-2-beta-17.htm

Comment: @Faisal: for me, your updated example (with `$event.metaKey`) does not work in neither Chrome nor Firefox nor Safari. For Cmd+S it brings the "Save webpage" dialog. Did you try to run it?

Comment: div by default is not focusable. I test with a input element. I have created a plunk for this, here is the link: https://plnkr.co/edit/xtaTjKzPwIDXpc77ZcUj?p=preview [I am trying to figure out how to stop the save dialog from opening]

Comment: @Faisal: so far the only thing that was able to capture command+s (key DOWN) - http://bennadel.github.io/JavaScript-Demos/demos/key-events-plugin-angular2/ - source https://github.com/bennadel/JavaScript-Demos/blob/master/demos/key-events-plugin-angular2/index.htm

Comment: @Faisal: for preventing save dialog, maybe: `$event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @Faisal - interestingly, for me your Plunkr does not seem to detect Cmd+S... Are you on a Mac?

Comment: I am on windows

Comment: @KarolDepka I have updated the plunker to detect the platform

Comment: @Faisal I accepted this answer, though the remaining question is how to get rid of the browser's page-save dialog hijacking the shortcut key, which we hope to solve soon ;-).

Comment: For global shortcuts, one can use the `window:` prefix, for example: `<div
  (window:keydown.meta.s)="keyDownSave($event)"
  (window:keydown.control.s)="keyDownSave($event)"
>`

Answer (score 17):

Global listener, non-deprecated answer:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if ((event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) && event.key === 's') {
        this.save();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The methods preventDefault() and stopPropagation() and so on did not work for me (using current Chrome), so i had to go multiple keys: ctrl+shift+s
2. When defining the event handler in my component, it only worked for this subsite and only if some form inputs were in focus, so i had to add the listener at another place.
3. I compressed the multiple functions, since i do not care about which environment the hotkey gets called, i want to save my object.

`ngOnInit() {   
  document.body.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    let charCode = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
    switch (((navigator.platform.match('Mac') && event.metaKey) || event.ctrlKey) && event.shiftKey && charCode === 's') {
      case true: {
        this.saveArticle(); //whatever your usecase is
        break;
      }
    }
  });
}`