# Event binding for specific keypress event

Tags: angular

In Angular I can write `<input (keyup.enter)"onEnter($event)">` to detect when user press Enter key.

The same I can do with other keys `esc`, `space`, `shift` etc.

**But how to detect when user press `shift` + `up`?**

**Is there a list with supported key combinations?** (I could'n find any in official docs)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some research I found neat way to do it:

```html
<!-- Listen to Shift + Up -->
<input (keyup.shift.arrowup)="...">

<!-- Listen to Ctrl + Shift + Down -->
<input (keyup.control.shift.arrowdown)="...">

<!-- Listen to Esc within window -->
<div (window:keyup.esc)="...">
```

**UPDATE**

After exploring angular sources ([here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/23a98b9e5134df3b96dd932173ce86384d72ada0/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/events/key_events.ts) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/platform-browser/test/dom/events/key_events_spec.ts)).

It turns out that general syntax for such event names is: **eventname.modifier.key**.
Where:
- **eventname**: *keydown* or *keyup*
- **modifier**: *alt*, *control*, *meta* or *shift* (can be more than one)
- **key**: key from [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property

Examples: `keyup.control.z`, `keyup.control.backspace`, `keyup.shift.pageup`, `keyup.alt.dot`.

Note that some combination may not work, e.g. `keyup.shift.tab`.

Comment: Could you possibly share the URL of where you found these? I'm looking for a more extensive list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `(keyup)` and check the `event` for which key was pressed, and for `shiftKey`:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="myFunc($event)"/>
```

**Function inside Component**

```
private myFunc(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
  if (event.key === 'ArrowUp' && event.shiftKey) {
    // Your code
  }
}
```

Comment: If this works I love it. I was going to suggest having a keydown event that checks for shift and sets a boolean to true. Then a key up function that sets that boolean to false if it was shift that was keyed up, but if it's the arrow key and the boolean is set to true then that's your shift + up situation.

Comment: It doesn't work. The function called only when I press `up`. It doesn't called when press `shift` + `up`, so I can't check if `event.shiftKey` is true.

Comment: @taras-d You are correct, no event was triggered when using `(keyup.arrowup)` while holding down `shift` unfortunately. I updated my answer.

Comment: @taras-d Then write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve it like this:

```
<input (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)">
```

.. and in your typescript code:

```
onKeyUp($event): void { 
    if ($event.shiftKey && $event.which === 38) {
        // Place your logic here
    } 
}
```

Here is a link to working **[PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/0dy939fgb5EKkLcxWCb2)**.

Comment: This is one of the possible solutions. But maybe there is a way to write something like this `(keyup.shift+up)="..."` !?

Comment: You have to put the `shift + up` logic in the method as i did. I am using the same in my project. See my another answer for a generic mac and windows solution for Ctrl + S: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45569055/1791913

Comment: I found the way I want to do it. I updated my question.

Comment: @taras-d interesting, neat solution :)

Comment: however, that solution will only be restricted to windows !

Comment: What do you mean? `(keyup.shift.arrowup)` - listen to event within element. `(window:keyup.shift.arrowup)` - listen to event within window.

Comment: I mean that, there is no control key in mac, metaKey is used instead. So any event that you specify with the `control` key will not work on mac.

Comment: I understand. I can't check, but I think `(keyup.meta.shift.arrowup)` should work on the mac.