# Vue.js / Vuex click function is not working for cmd + click

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to fire a function for cmd + click. But it looks impossible at least for my keyboard.

My keyboard type:

> Macbook Turkish Q

It seems like because of Macbook CMD key works depend on browser, How can I set new key codes for vue.js easily?

```
<div @click="foo($event)" ></div>

foo(e){
console.log(e.ctrlKey) // If I press CMD and Click to DIV result always FALSE
console.log(e.shiftKey) // If I press SHIFT and Click to DIV result TRUE (shift working but cmd is not working)
}
```

Comment: See [this question](How does one capture a Mac's command key via JavaScript?)

Comment: How can I change key codes In a component of Vuex?

Comment: just cheking `e.metaKey` now and it's working, thank you! In my case, does not matter If click cmd or shift, I just need that if click cmd + click it sjould fire the function so, `e.metaKey` solved my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one capture a Mac's command key via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript) ? No it't not, this one is specific to Vuex which I missed.

Comment: Why not post an answer for the next guy ? I'll upvote it if you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check `e.metaKey` it works! it handles CMD now.

Thank you.