# How to check if command key is pressed while clicking on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have overridden the `onClick` function of anchor() tag in ReactJs to show loading.

```
const child: ReactElement = Children.only(children);

const childProps = {};

childProps['onClick'] = (event) => {

    if (childProps.href && child.props.target !== '_blank') {
        props.showSpinner(true);
    }

    let onClick = child.props.onClick;
    onClick && onClick();
};

return React.cloneElement(child, childProps);
```

But the problem is that if the user clicks on `anchor(<a>)` with `shift` and `command` keypress, then the user switches to the new tab but loading started showing.

So I added the following condition to show loading.

```
if (!event.shiftKey && childProps.href && child.props.target !== '_blank') {
   props.showSpinner(true);
}
```

This code handled the Shift key press but I have to handle `command` keypress also.
I searched through many posts, they showing solution for `alt, shift, and ctl` keypress but not command keypress.

Comment: This question has already been answered [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript)

Comment: @MSoheb Thanks, But I have <a> tag with `href` and only can override `onClick` and in this method, event.keyCode is giving undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check value of `event.metaKey` inside `onClick` of a button.

```
    <button
      onClick={e => {
        console.log("CLICKED", e.metaKey);
      }}
    >
      Press
    </button>
```

In above example, You will get value of `e.metaKey` as `true` if command is pressed.

Comment: for docs about event.metaKey : [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand when we are working with React, window object is not available directly, have you tried with componentDidMount function

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library that uses mouse modifiers to select things similar to how you can on operating systems!

Anyways, there is an example of detecting if the user is on Mac os and handling the meta key in the source code. Check out the pivot reducer.

https://github.com/ssteuteville/react-selection-hooks