# how to override the default cmd shortcut key in ubuntu using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

command + C in my application I want to open the menu button. By default command key executed behalf of command + c. How to override the command key

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the default key combination action to be executed using the **preventDefault** function:

```
function KeyPress(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var evtobj = window.event ? event : e;
    if (evtobj.keyCode == 80 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
        console.log("Key combination: Ctrl + p");
    }
}

document.onkeydown = KeyPress;
```

The `document.onkeydown` sentence is adding the event function to all the document, so it will be triggered when any element in the website is selected/focused.

---

Unfortunately, like is answered in this post [How does one capture a Mac's command key via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript), there is not an standard key code for the iOS command key, and it is browser dependant:

- Firefox: 224
- Opera: 17
- WebKit browsers (Safari/Chrome): 91 (Left Command) or 93 (Right Command)

You can check the key codes here: https://keycode.info/