# How to accomplish CTRL + F & CMD + F functionality with Javascript at the same time

Tags: javascript, dom, events, keycode

I want to enable both `ctrl + f` & `cmd + f` with `Javascript`. So far, I have been able to perform the `ctrl + f` functionality, but I can't figure out how to enable both.

This is what I have so far:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) {
        alert('working');
    }
})
```

This is a [code playground](https://jsfiddle.net/joe628m0/).

**EDIT 1:** Even better if I can run `cmd + f` on Mac or `ctrl + f` on Windows.

**EDIT 2:** I tried the following [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript), but I couldn't make work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work like so:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70) || (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70) || (e.metaKey && e.keyCode === 70))) {
        alert('working');
    }
})
```

This is a [working code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/5z4kwne6/1/).