# Is there any way to collect data from console to javascript?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I want to take input from the console and process it for another function.
Is there any way to do that instead of setting those datas as variable before logging them to console.

```html
<html><head><script>

/*

 * based on JavaScript Client Detecting by viazenetti GmbH (Christian Ludwig)

 */ 

(function (window) {

    {

        var unknown = '-';

        

        // screen

        var screenSize = '';

        if (screen.width) {

            width = (screen.width) ? screen.width : '';

            height = (screen.height) ? screen.height : '';

            screenSize += '' + width + " × " + height;

        }

        // browser

        var nVer = navigator.appVersion;

        var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;

        var browser = navigator.appName;

        var version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);

        var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);

        var nameOffset, verOffset, ix;

        // Opera

        if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Opera')) != -1) {

            browser = 'Opera';

            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 6);

            if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {

                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);

            }

        }

        // Opera Next

        if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('OPR')) != -1) {

            browser = 'Opera';

            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 4);

        }

        // MSIE

        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('MSIE')) != -1) {

            browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';

            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 5);

        }

        // Chrome

        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Chrome')) != -1) {

            browser = 'Chrome';

            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);

        }

        // Safari

        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Safari')) != -1) {

            browser = 'Safari';

            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);

            if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {

                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);

            }

        }

        // Firefox

        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Firefox')) != -1) {

            browser = 'Firefox';

            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);

        }

        // MSIE 11+

        else if (nAgt.indexOf('Trident/') != -1) {

            browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';

            version = nAgt.substring(nAgt.indexOf('rv:') + 3);

        }

        // Other browsers

        else if ((nameOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1) < (verOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf('/'))) {

            browser = nAgt.substring(nameOffset, verOffset);

            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 1);

            if (browser.toLowerCase() == browser.toUpperCase()) {

                browser = navigator.appName;

            }

        }

        // trim the version string

        if ((ix = version.indexOf(';')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);

        if ((ix = version.indexOf(' ')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);

        if ((ix = version.indexOf(')')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);

        majorVersion = parseInt('' + version, 10);

        if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {

            version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);

            majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);

        }

        // mobile version

        var mobile = /Mobile|mini|Fennec|Android|iP(ad|od|hone)/.test(nVer);

        // cookie

        var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

        if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == 'undefined' && !cookieEnabled) {

            document.cookie = 'testcookie';

            cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf('testcookie') != -1) ? true : false;

        }

        // system

        var os = unknown;

        var clientStrings = [

            {s:'Windows 10', r:/(Windows 10.0|Windows NT 10.0)/},

            {s:'Windows 8.1', r:/(Windows 8.1|Windows NT 6.3)/},

            {s:'Windows 8', r:/(Windows 8|Windows NT 6.2)/},

            {s:'Windows 7', r:/(Windows 7|Windows NT 6.1)/},

            {s:'Windows Vista', r:/Windows NT 6.0/},

            {s:'Windows Server 2003', r:/Windows NT 5.2/},

            {s:'Windows XP', r:/(Windows NT 5.1|Windows XP)/},

            {s:'Windows 2000', r:/(Windows NT 5.0|Windows 2000)/},

            {s:'Windows ME', r:/(Win 9x 4.90|Windows ME)/},

            {s:'Windows 98', r:/(Windows 98|Win98)/},

            {s:'Windows 95', r:/(Windows 95|Win95|Windows_95)/},

            {s:'Windows NT 4.0', r:/(Windows NT 4.0|WinNT4.0|WinNT|Windows NT)/},

            {s:'Windows CE', r:/Windows CE/},

            {s:'Windows 3.11', r:/Win16/},

            {s:'Android', r:/Android/},

            {s:'Open BSD', r:/OpenBSD/},

            {s:'Sun OS', r:/SunOS/},

            {s:'Linux', r:/(Linux|X11)/},

            {s:'iOS', r:/(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/},

            {s:'Mac OS X', r:/Mac OS X/},

            {s:'Mac OS', r:/(MacPPC|MacIntel|Mac_PowerPC|Macintosh)/},

            {s:'QNX', r:/QNX/},

            {s:'UNIX', r:/UNIX/},

            {s:'BeOS', r:/BeOS/},

            {s:'OS/2', r:/OS\/2/},

            {s:'Search Bot', r:/(nuhk|Googlebot|Yammybot|Openbot|Slurp|MSNBot|Ask Jeeves\/Teoma|ia_archiver)/}

        ];

        for (var id in clientStrings) {

            var cs = clientStrings[id];

            if (cs.r.test(nAgt)) {

                os = cs.s;

                break;

            }

        }

        var osVersion = unknown;

        if (/Windows/.test(os)) {

            osVersion = /Windows (.*)/.exec(os)[1];

            os = 'Windows';

        }

        switch (os) {

            case 'Mac OS X':

                osVersion = /Mac OS X (10[\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];

                break;

            case 'Android':

                osVersion = /Android ([\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];

                break;

            case 'iOS':

                osVersion = /OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/.exec(nVer);

                osVersion = osVersion[1] + '.' + osVersion[2] + '.' + (osVersion[3] | 0);

                break;

        }

        

        // flash (you'll need to include swfobject)

        /* script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js" */

        var flashVersion = 'no check';

        if (typeof swfobject != 'undefined') {

            var fv = swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion();

            if (fv.major > 0) {

                flashVersion = fv.major + '.' + fv.minor + ' r' + fv.release;

            }

            else  {

                flashVersion = unknown;

            }

        }

    }

    window.jscd = {

        screen: screenSize,

        browser: browser,

        browserVersion: version,

        browserMajorVersion: majorVersion,

        mobile: mobile,

        os: os,

        osVersion: osVersion,

        cookies: cookieEnabled,

        flashVersion: flashVersion

    };

}(this));

console.log(

    'OS: ' + jscd.os +' '+ jscd.osVersion + '\n' +

    'Browser: ' + jscd.browser +' '+ jscd.browserMajorVersion +

      ' (' + jscd.browserVersion + ')\n' + 

    'Mobile: ' + jscd.mobile + '\n' +

    'Flash: ' + jscd.flashVersion + '\n' +

    'Cookies: ' + jscd.cookies + '\n' +

    'Screen Size: ' + jscd.screen + '\n\n' +

    'Full User Agent: ' + navigator.userAgent

);

// http://stackoverflow.com/a/3922353/846193

/* MAC Key Binding on Browsers

Firefox: 224

Opera: 17

WebKit (Safari/Chrome): 91 (Left Apple) or 93 (Right Apple)

*/

var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

    // Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)

var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+

var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;

    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"

var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              // Chrome 1+

var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; // At least IE6

</script></head>

<body bgcolor="lightgray">

Output is in console.
Check them through developers mode

</body></html>
```

---

I tried every possible ways as solutions and read multiple blogs but none of them giving efficient answer in this case. Especially when it comes to **JavaScript** console.

I can't set them as variable before this script completely compiled. So is there any way to collect those datas from console.

[ The given code logs data about user's device specifications to console.
eg: Operating system, Browser, is a bot?, Is Cookies enabled? ]

Comment: Why do you need to take input from the console?

Comment: If you are logging the data to the console, why not just use the original data?

Comment: It is not at all clear what that big block of code you posted has to do with the question.

Comment: My point is to collect the information. I summarised that code at the bottom. Because reading all of the code is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines in the code you are presenting:

```
console.log(

    'OS: ' + jscd.os +' '+ jscd.osVersion + '\n' +

    'Browser: ' + jscd.browser +' '+ jscd.browserMajorVersion +

      ' (' + jscd.browserVersion + ')\n' + 

    'Mobile: ' + jscd.mobile + '\n' +

    'Flash: ' + jscd.flashVersion + '\n' +

    'Cookies: ' + jscd.cookies + '\n' +

    'Screen Size: ' + jscd.screen + '\n\n' +

    'Full User Agent: ' + navigator.userAgent

);
```

Are those who print the output in the console. So if you want to reuse any of this values in Js you just need to reference to the matching variable. So for example: OS is stored in the javascript variable `jscd.os` and its version is in the javascript variable `jscd.osVersion`

Comment: Is there any way to collect complete data which is already stored in console. Because sometimes we may add error warnings too in user's log. Which is not being accessible in my case for further analysis.

Comment: the point is that you put things in the console. So you have already all the things that are displayed. there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so via prompt as easy as:

```js
const input = prompt("What's your name?");

console.log(input);
```