# make HTML/jQuery object non-hightlightable

Tags: jquery, html

I have an `<input>` element for which I would like to make it impossible to highlight the content.

Comment: onselectstart="return false" doesn't work for inputs

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable text selection using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#input").mousedown(function(e) { return false; } ).click(function(e){$(this).focus()});
```