# How to disable text selection via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this question have been already asked ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery)), but all the answers I've found dealt with css
selector :selection (that is not yet too widely supported by browsers).

So, how can I disable text selection on my html page via jQuery, not relying on css tricks?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try that http://code.jdempster.com/jQuery.DisableTextSelect/jquery.disable.text.select.js

Comment: It seems cross-browser enough, thnx!

Comment: This was a good solution, but unfortunately `$.browser` has been removed as of 1.9 so this will fail.

Comment: The link is broken... And also this is not correct solution - Halfhoof's is correct and should be accepted.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a simple one-liner to disable selecting text on your whole page.  (whether you should or not is another question)

```
$(document).bind('selectstart dragstart', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple, elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks, even works with jQuery-UI if you remove the `dragstart`

Answer (score 12):

If you want to avoid plugins, you can extract the relevant parts from the jQuery UI source:

```
/*!
 * jQuery UI 1.8.16
 *
 * Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * http://docs.jquery.com/UI
 */
$.support.selectstart = "onselectstart" in document.createElement("div");
$.fn.disableSelection = function() {
    return this.bind( ( $.support.selectstart ? "selectstart" : "mousedown" ) +
        ".ui-disableSelection", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
};

$("#somediv").disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 4):

Include jQuery UI and use `$(element).disableSelection()`.

However, disabling text selection is **very** user-unfriendly unless used in a context where accidental selections are likely (e.g. Drag&Drop or buttons where users are likely to doubleclick to perform multiple changes faster (e.g. in spinners))

Comment: all right, but I'd prefer not to add any plugins because I'm operating on 3-rd party website that has only jquery plugged in (injecting my small javascript snippet)