# Losing selected text from contenteditable on clicking div with css user-select: none;

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, contenteditable

I'm developing a JavaScript rich text editor. Instead of buttons, I'm using div with css property `user-select: none`. This works fine in Firefox but **problem is with Google Chrome**.

When I click on div with css `user-select: none`, I'm losing the selected text from contenteditable div. Html and css is given below

```
<div id="editor">
   <div id="controls">
      <div id="button-bold"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="rte" contenteditable></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#button-bold
{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #E7E7E5;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
#rte {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: 5px;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I have a similar setup, and the following solution works fine in Chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery

Comment: Thankyou, problem was with selectstart event.

Comment: No problem.  I have put this as the answer below so you can close off this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar setup, and the following solution works fine in Chrome:
[How to disable text selection using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery)

The answer is to add a handler for the 'selectstart' event.

Answer (score 1):

Use buttons, intead of div or span for making clickable links to change style.

And then use document.execcommand('forecolor',false,'#000000');