# Drawing rectangles (divs) with the mouse

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mousemove

I am trying to draw rectangles (divs) using mouse events. Here is my code:

http://jsbin.com/apediti/2/edit

Basically I'm doing the following:

1. On `mousedown` I save the mouse coordinates, create a new div with size: `width=0`, `height=0`, and bind event handlers for `mousemove` and `mouseup`.
2. On `mousemove` I resize the div based on the current mouse position.
3. On `mouseup` I unbind the event handlers for `mousemove` and `mouseup`.

It seems to work good in Firefox, and even IE 10, but in Chrome sometimes the `mousemove` event fires only 2 or 3 times, after mousedown, so the drawn div doesn't get resized.

I can't find the reason why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Works for me in latest Chrome - do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console, and the 'bug' only appears sometimes. Try this for example: draw a rectangle, and when you draw a second one make sure to release the mouse when you are over the first div. Now try to create a 3th rectangle. The bug should appear. Does it? (Thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because Chrome is attempting to select the hovered-over `rect` element on drag. To fix this, simply prevent the `rect` element from being selected by setting the [`user-select` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) to `none` (this is [vendor prefixed](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/) and [will not work on IE9 or lower](http://caniuse.com/#feat=user-select-none)):

```css
.rect {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid rgba(199, 25, 9, 0.64);
    -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox all */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: none;  
}
```

[**Modified JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/EdaCIrI/1/edit).

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. It works fine now. Big thanks for that. I would love to find a javascript solution for this, to make it cross browser compatible. Any ideas for a javascript solution?

Comment: @TamasPap as you're using jQuery, SLaks' answer here should do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery

Comment: Thanks James. Now it works as expected. Appreciated your help!