# Need help finding what is blocking text selection in script

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, particles

I am using the following mobile-me script that can be seen here:

```
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/mobileme-particles/
```

I have noticed that it is blocking my ability to select text on the site.  For example if you use your mouse to select “Created by: lokesh dhakar” at the footer of the page, it cannot be done.

Here is the github repository:

```
https://github.com/lokesh/mobileme-particles
```

I need help finding what is blocking the text from being selected in this project.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start with words of wisdom :

> Disabling text selection is bad. Don't use this.

From http://api.jqueryui.com/disableselection/

```
.disableSelection()
```

Otherwise you can change the background of your text selection to match the other background

```
::selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; 
}
```

or from : [How to disable text selection using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery)

```
(function($){
  $.fn.disableSelection = function() {
    return this
             .attr('unselectable', 'on')
             .css('user-select', 'none')
             .on('selectstart', false);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

EDIT : (From me and Presto) add
`Modernizr.addTest("userselect",function(){     return Modernizr.testAllProps("user-select"); });` to the js file and I can now select the text :)

Comment: Thank you for the wise words.  I am trying to take it out of this script.  I will search now to see if this is listed there.

Comment: I didn't too... don't know where it's hidden. If you do a CTRL+A you can select the text though

Comment: well thanks for checking.  I will keep searching and hopefully find it.

Comment: try look inside the modernizr plugin I just found a mention of user-select here [link](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/250)

Comment: That does it, thanks!  I just had to add `Modernizr.addTest("userselect",function(){
    return Modernizr.testAllProps("user-select");
});` to the `js` file and I can now select the text :)  If you want to note this in your answer I will award it right away.

Comment: Unfortunately this also breaks the particles from displaying... ohh well.  I'll keep working with it.